# Part of ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, responsetext

Can you please tell me how to obtain a certain part from ajax responseText?

Example:

```
<div id="first">Text1<div>
<div id="second">I want to use this text<div>
<div id="third">Text 3<div>
```

I thought about passing the responseText to a div, and then accessing it with document.getElementById('id'), but i thing there are better ways.

Comment: have you try this with json???

Comment: set response type to dom document and do getElementByWhatever directly on the response.

Comment: Doing what you suggest with a div, xplicitly: Creating a new div with `var myDiv = document.createElement("div")` and then doing `myDiv.innerHTML = responseText; var text myDiv.querySelector("#third");` might actually be pretty ok.

Comment: Or, if you only support really new browsers - what Awal said is probably better.

Comment: @all even I corrected my answer with javascript version it was downvoted and proposed for deleting. Why  Awal Garg do not give a better suggestion instead for downvoting my answer. What is the problem of using regexp sorry?

Comment: the thing that I dont get about the downvotes on @albanx answer is not only did it propose a way to do it with javascript. other passers by can also see a jQuery way to do it.... seems like a good answer for the community.

Comment: As I have discuss in chat some time ago, SO is getting more to a wikipedia edit-war rather then a real website for helping and finding good solution with community.

Comment: @JohnRuddell and the other thing that I do not get, is that people does not discuss about the solution itself (making it better suggesting) but they discuss about it out of context. This does not happened at the first years of SO.

Comment: @albanx see here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077 i think it sums it up pretty well.

Comment: @JohnRuddell totally agree, that is the question I have been searching for, so I am not the only one who feels the same.